# Gradle build error - bug?

Tags: android

I'm getting a strange error when making signed app:

```
:app:compileReleaseAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
null value in entry: sourceOutputDir=null
```

happened after update studio, but other projects are fine

i've already made clean / rebuild / delete gradle dir from project / lowered gradle version / even rollback from git

What else should i try?

Comment: try to delete build folder inside app app/build

Comment: Did not helped.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null and I have to mark this question as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null)

Comment: that topic did not helped, watched this before.
finally fixed by creating new project and copying code