# Error:null value in entry: destinationDir=null in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I want to generate my application in android studio it makes a mistake:

> Error:null value in entry: destinationDir=null

It was right yesterday, but it has problem today.
I also `Clean` and `Rebuild` my project but doesn't work.

Comment: No one has any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reinstalled Android studio and Gradle and copied my project into new project and it's solved.

Answer (score 10):

I also face this sort of issue.With help of the [Error:null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null) issue is solved.

> Just remove the .gradle directory in the root project directory

Comment: Your error is different. I don't have .gradle folder!

Answer (score 1):

[Ghimire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46661125/1799007) is right, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248713/1799007) and the referenced [gradle forums post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/null-value-in-entry-dependencycachedir-null/19191).

.gradle is a hidden folder, so you'll have to

```
$ ls -a
```

or, if you want them to show up in Finder

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true
$ killall Finder
```