# Error:null value in entry: annotationProcessorOutputFolder=null?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am trying to compile my android project and getting the error

> null value in entry: `annotationProcessorOutputFolder=null`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Delete the .gradle folder containing the local cache and rebuilding the project again.  fix the problem for me.

Comment: Make sure you delete .gradle (and not gradle) and be aware it could be hidden. Use the Project view to see it.
Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue.You can delete your .gradle folder hidden inside project view and build your project again. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and deleted the .gradle folder containing the local cache,but it didn't work . I updated the gradle. this fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have stuck in the Issue like this What resolve my problem is ...

Invalidate and restart the Android Studio-> Clean Project -> Rebuilt Again