# Android studio not building gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I want to debug my application I get the error:

> Error:null value in entry: fakeOutputDirectory=null

in Android Studio in "messages". Any suggestions how I can fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null

Comment: thank you so much!! that solved it, please write it as an answer so i can give the correct answer to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Delete your .gradle file

2 Rebuild your project

3 Clean your project

4 Now install APK.

if the issue is still disabled instant run

goto File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Answer (score 0):

1)Remove `.gradle` directory in the root project directory.
2)Rebuild app