# I am unable to build my APK help me how to fix it

Tags: android, android-studio

when I am trying to generate apk, I am getting the below error.How to solve it?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Wrong classpath: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found

This is my gradle console

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20:03:2018 android/app/google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Wrong classpath: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

20 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

--stacktrace

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Wrong classpath: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Wrong classpath: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wrong classpath: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found
    at com.android.multidex.Path.<init>(Path.java:60)
    at com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.<init>(MainDexListBuilder.java:113)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.callDx(MainDexListTransform.java:292)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.computeList(MainDexListTransform.java:264)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:186)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found
    at com.android.multidex.Path.getClassPathElement(Path.java:45)
    at com.android.multidex.Path.<init>(Path.java:58)
    ... 46 more
```

--app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.bca.bca"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {

    defaultConfig {

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

-- project level gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks inAdvance

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File "/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20" not found` Check the path if desired file exists there.

Comment: yes b.i have tried .no use

Comment: yes .file is there in specified path.@Rohit5k2

Comment: @Gowthami can you please share me your build.gradle file of your app module

Comment: I have updated the question please check it

Comment: What does the folder `/Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20:03:2018 
 android` contain?

Comment: Folder name of complete android app

Comment: @Gowthami You'll need to change the name of the app folder then, Gradle doesn't like `:` characters in file paths. See my answer below.

Comment: Error:null value in entry: otherFolderOutputs.otherFolderOutput1=null.     When I renamed I got this  error

Answer (score 0):

Please check this json file path if possible change json file path and try to build application.

```
 Parsing json file: /Users/gowthamichintha/Downloads/20:03:2018 
 android/app/google-services.json
```

Comment: can  you explain me in detail

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated keywords for implement external repositories. Please follow this steps.

Add `google()` repo into your `project>build.gradle` like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() //this is for to download Google's repo like admob, playservices,maps firebase and all
        jcenter() 
    }
}
```

Now in your `app>build.gradle` replace all **compile** keywords with **implementation**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project is within an invalidly-named folder (`20:03:2018 
 android`). While having colons `:` in a folder name may be valid for Unix, it can cause problems in other applications. For example, in Gradle (as demonstrated in [this bug report](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-1-8-copy-task-fails-when-source-file-contains-colon/1747)), the colon is a reserved key character, a separator specifying that a particular build type is going to be applied to a module.

I would recommend renaming your project folder into something more Gradle-friendly, for example use hyphens and underscores instead i.e.: `20-03-2018_android`. Make sure to close Android Studio first, and open the project manually next time you open Android Studio.

Comment: Error:null value in entry: otherFolderOutputs.otherFolderOutput1=null        When I renamed  I got this error

Comment: @Gowthami Did you clean the build before rebuilding?

Comment: @Gowthami Alternatively, delete or move the `.gradle` folder before rebuilding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null

Comment: Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.          I got this error

Comment: @Gowthami Can you post your project-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Gowthami That looks fine, I'm struggling to see why it's not picking up the Android plugin. What happens when you type `./gradlew clean build` from the terminal?