# error in creating new android studio project

Tags: java, android

Hi i recently ran into some problem related to creating new project in android studio. Whenever i create a new project in android studio project is not getting created properly even the structure is getting generated differently i dont what has happened you can see the images below to understand the problem.
[image: First image]
[image: Second image]
This has started happening when i faced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) problem so it was suggested that i remove .gradle file and after that i'm not able to create new project.

**EDIT** my grdle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: share you `Gradle` file

Comment: only project level build.gradle is getting generated

Comment: post your Gradel file, and your Module gradle is not Build that's why it is showing error like this. Have you implemented any module explicitly?
.

Comment: No i have no idea about module explicity and how can i solve this problem

Comment: @farhana please see i have edited my post

Comment: What is the version of android studio?

Comment: @Ishan my android version is 3.1.0

Comment: can i redownload my .gradle file which i removed to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197045/errornull-value-in-entry-incrementalfolder-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: In your screenshot, it  is visible that your project has a library or module,

Comment: but app level gradle is missing it is not getting generated

Comment: what should i do

Comment: I think it's good to try install Android studio from scratch

Comment: @Ishan Fernando can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304967/how-to-get-image-from-intent-of-recyclerview-in-viewpager